# showing data from mysql database into listbox (data selected from combobox) c#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

So i m trying to display data from database into listbox. But the data i want to see i select in the combobox so i open combobox select the data and then it should display me some numbers i was trying something but i m not really sure if its right pls help me out

the code:

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
        string Query = "Select ocena From filmi.film Where film = @film"; ;
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@film", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(myReader);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the field that you want to add to the listbox

```
listBox2.Items.Add(myReader["ocena"].ToString());
```

If there is the possibility that the field ocena contains null values then you need to

```
string ocenaValue = (myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("ocena")) ?
                    string.Empty, myReader["ocena"].ToString());
listBox2.Items.Add(ocenaValue);
```

As a final tip, I suggest to use the Using Statement around the disposable objects. In that way your connection, command and reader will be closed and disposed when you have finished to use them also in case of exceptions

```
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
    string Query = "Select ocena From filmi.film Where film = @film"; ;
    using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
    {
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@film", this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
            {
               while (myReader.Read())
               {
                   string ocenaValue = (myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("ocena")) ?
                                       string.Empty : myReader["ocena"].ToString());
                   listBox2.Items.Add(ocenaValue);
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i do it like this i get this error `'myReader' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'
`

Comment: where should i put the string ocenaValue cuz if i only add `listBox2.Items.Add(myReader["ocena"].ToString());` it doesnt work

Comment: Do you have any errors displayed or simply there is no data in the listbox? If no data present then is possible that there is no record corresponding to your parameter?

Comment: if i add `listBox2.Items.Add(myReader["ocena"].ToString());` there is no data in listbox if i put all the things u writed i get 9 errors like `;` errors and those like the code is wrong `; expected
`

Comment: Again fixed the answer for the missing :. I think you should used the debugger to check why there is no data. Put a breakpoint on  the ExecuteReader line and then proceed step by step to be sure that the loop is executed at least one time. Look also at the value in SelectedItem if it is what you expect to be.

Comment: got an error at `IsDbNull` says ` 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsDbNull' and no extension method 'IsDbNull' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
`

Comment: Oh well, typing without the help of intellisense is difficult. IsDBNull (note the upper case B)

Answer (score 0):

Is Ocena a database table or item in the table? Refer to the column name, rather than the item or database table, and you'll get your data. e.g.

listBox2.Items.Add(myReader["film"].ToString());

will give you all the items in the column film

It's been long since you posted, but it could help someone else.